# Select post with specific group - subfield value

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

in wordpress I have custom post type 'referenzen'. This post type has Custom fields(ACF) 'Referenzen-buildin-type' Group with subfield 'building-type' which is checkbox. I do not know how to select posts with specific building type. This is not working for me :

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
  'meta_query' => array(
      array(
          'key'     => 'referenzen-building-types_building-type',
          'value'   => '"Museen"',
          'compare' => 'LIKE'
      )
  )
));
```

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look below:

```
<?php
  //args
  $args = = array (
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'event',
    'meta_key'      => 'location',
    'meta_value'    => 'Melbourne'
  );

  //query
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );?>

<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
  <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    /* do something */
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
```

I hope it would help you out.

Comment: Please do not forget to change the post type name and others parameter

Comment: Thanks, the only thing I forgot to add in $args is the post type. Probably, this is necessary because it is a custom post type. With 'post_type' it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
  'meta_query' => array(
      array(
          'key'     => 'referenzen_building_types_building_type',
          'value'   => 'Museen',
          'compare' => 'LIKE'
      )
  )
));
```

Comment: Thank you,but this also return empty array

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/2648551) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!